# optimise and merge sql queries into one - newbie alert

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how is the best way to merge these sql queries from the db.

I'm using this but wants to add the two others into it if possible

```
SELECT m.username, sum(d.liter) AS TOT_LITERS, min(krl) AS TOT_KM
FROM members m JOIN
     diesel d
     ON (d.userid = m.id)
WHERE d.dato >= '$dx'
GROUP BY m.username
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

and the other two

```
SELECT SUM(liter) AS totalfuel
FROM diesel
WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx' AND userid = ".$_COOKIE['userid']."
ORDER BY diesel.dato DESC

SELECT MIN(km) AS minikm, MAX(km) AS maxkm
FROM diesel
WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx' AND userid = ".$_COOKIE['userid']."
ORDER BY diesel.dato DESC
```

They all three does what I expected them to, but I guess there has to be a better way than having three queries on the same page

Is UNION the way to go here ? I don't see how though cause they need to have the same amount of tables :P ?

EDIT: Well I don't need the user ID and that cookie thing this time. Just forgot to remove it. I'm making a highscore and would like to show the usernames, average gas, km driven, liters filled etc ..

Comment: A UNION statement joins two queries that output the exact same fields, so that wouldn't work here.  You would have to find a way to put it all into a single query - probably using sub-queries.

Comment: Thanks, how does sub-queries work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a sub-query:

```
SELECT m.username,
    (
        SELECT SUM(liter) AS SumOfLiters
        FROM diesel
        WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx'
        AND diesel.IDField = d.IDField
    ) AS TotalFuel
FROM members m
    JOIN diesel d ON d.userid = m.id
WHERE d.dato >= '$dx'
```

The sub-query (in brackets) returns a value that you can assign to a field (TotalFuel in this case).

Comment: So if I wanted 2 or 3 sub queries I would just add them too in brackets just after the first one in your example ?

Comment: Yep, as many as you need, at least until the query starts getting slow.  Then you'll have to look at finding ways to optimize it.

Answer (score -1):

rather than restricting everything in the where clause then trying to marry it all back you could use your top query with a few sum case whens e.g.

```
sum(case when userid = '.$_COOKIE['userid'].' then liter else 0 end)
```